# CUDAQ crashes the kernel

Tags: neural-networks

**Bug introduced in 11.2 and fixed in 12.0.0**

It appears that the following code will **crash** Mathematica kernel:

```
LinearLayer[5]
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAQ[]
```

I'm using Mathematica 11.2 on macos 10.12.6. Is it reproducible on other platforms?

Comment: An aside: Neural net training does not use CUDA so you don't need to load ``CUDALink` ``.

Comment: @Edmund If we want to use GPU for training, CUDA is needed.

Comment: But CUDALink should not be needed. The neural network functionality comes with its own set of libraries and can access the GPU without CUDALink. Having said that, the crash is certainly a bug that should be fixed and I have filed a bug report.

Answer (score 3):

This should be fixed in *Mathematica* 12.0.0.